# Why doesn’t the ACT light blink or even turn on?

Tags: act

So I have the Pi 3 B+ and I haven’t used it in a long time. So I decided to bring it out and try it. When I turned it on Nothing happened. Only the power light was on and nothing was even showing up on the monitor. So I looked at it and the ACT light wasn’t even on. I have used this in the past but it was just sitting around and now won’t work.

Comment: you will have to answer your own question by doing some troubleshooting ... start by verifying that the power supply is operational

Comment: to add to that checklist, *"is there an SD card in it?"*. also, might you (or prev user) have disabled the ACT LED through `/boot/config.txt`?